# raspberry pi 3 iot agent unable to connect cumulocity platform

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have installed `noobs v2_4_5 in raspberry pi 3 model` ,configured `JAVA_HOME`, enabled `SSH` and set up static IP as well. I downloaded IOT agent cumulocity-`rpi-agent-latest.deb` and installed using the following 2 commands

```
$ wget http://resources.cumulocity.com/examples/cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cumulocity-rpi-agent-latest.deb
```

I registered the device in cumulocity platform. When agent is installed I should update cfg file `cumulocity.properties` located at `/usr/share/cumulocity-rpi-agent/cfg`. The file needs the following.

```
host
bootstrap.tenant
bootstrap.user
bootstrap.password
```

My account url is - `arpita.cumulocity.com`. What exactly I have to put in that file and any thing more I have to do to make active connection? Also `device.properties` file is not generating after agent installation. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer to this question.

---

After registering your `raspberry Pi 3` on Cumulocity and updating your `cumulocity.properties` file, you need to enable SPI.

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/08/enabling-the-spi-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/) is a reference how to do that.

After SPI is enabled, you will see your device status on Cumulocity is waiting for you to accept the connection.